# Setting a variable in a check makes .test faster than .indexOf

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, indexof

I saw [in this test bench](https://jsperf.com/exec-vs-match-vs-test-vs-search/5) that `indexOf` can perform around 10 times faster than using `test` with regex (varies a bit, because benchmarking).

I have some code that could literally make thousands of checks where this is relevant, so I switched it out. But I decided to run tests on it anyway, just to make sure it was working.

What I found is that in my code, `indexOf` runs only about 2 times faster than `test`.

This didn't make sense to me; I thought it might be the tester. So I added in the code from jsPerf back over to jsbench (where I was testing my own code), and the results were the same.

The only difference is that a variable's value is changed when `indexOf` doesn't find any results.

[Here is the test page.](http://jsbench.github.io/#994cc25867f34646dcfbbddf9257c8ff)

What is going on?

Tested in Google Chrome 63.0.3239.84.

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing this answer, I performed another test and figured it out. I thought I'd share the answer because it's really interesting.

The places where I set a variable were slower because the variable I was changing inside the block was the variable that I was checking!

```
//indexOf; adjust input
if(input.indexOf("abc")!==-1) {
    input="test";
}
```

When I instead adjusted another variable:

```
//indexOf; adjust input
if(input.indexOf("abc")!==-1) {
    potato="test";
}
```

The performance shot back up!

My guess is the browser was caching the result, which resulted in the improved speed. Alternatively, it stores the variable in such a way that changing it messes with `indexOf` checks in a way that can have dire effects on performance.

So when it comes to large-scale `indexOf` checks and responses, make sure you're not changing the variable you're checking in the results! At least in Google Chrome. :)

### Edit

Okay, different results with a [different test set](http://jsbench.github.io/#8a0c2f5baba00c4b49e4008f70e91228).

Regex is actually *faster* in this case than `indexOf`. Larger check set. The extra variable slows it down. That doesn't surprise me, but the huge shift does.

So the other results must just be all about results caching, and that's what makes `indexOf` look so much faster. At least, that's my guess.

Fun and interesting tests, I'd say the greatest lesson I learned from this isn't to take other people's tests as proof that you'll get the same results in your project. Test the speed of your own code against the speed of your slightly different own code- that's the only way to get helpful results.

Peace!

### Edit 2

Aaaand removing lowercase makes them both neck-and-neck. [Updated the test here.](http://jsbench.github.io/#8a0c2f5baba00c4b49e4008f70e91228)